# Field of a Foreignkey using Django

Tags: python, sql, database, django

I'm Making an App using Django in the model I don't want the id from the Foreignkey I want another field like the name

I Got something like this

```
class Musician(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    instrument = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Musician)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    release_date = models.DateField()
    num_stars = models.IntegerField()
```

I Want to Filter for musician and gave me an error

```
Exception Type:    DatabaseError
Exception Value:    no such column
```

Comment: You must have added a column without adding it in your database..

Comment: too expand a bit on @YujiTomita comment. If you add a column to the table after you ran manage.py sqlall (or similar forget), originally, rerunning manage.py will not update the db with the new column. You want something like django-south for handling these migrations or manually add the column yourself the table (I suggest something like django-south).